# Change the background color of a row in gridview on mouse hover in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you highlight the row and/or column labels of a datagridview on mouseover of any cell (in c#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944187/how-do-you-highlight-the-row-and-or-column-labels-of-a-datagridview-on-mouseover)

I am developing a windows forms application in which I need to change the background color of a gridview on mouse hover on the row.

Comment: Already asked before.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944187/how-do-you-highlight-the-row-and-or-column-labels-of-a-datagridview-on-mouseover